# django-markdown error: WSGI request object has not attribute 'REQUEST'

Tags: django, markdown

I am trying to install the django markdown editor https://github.com/klen/django_markdown

and I am getting now markdown rendering in my final text. I also get an error printed to the log when I try to use the 'preview' button...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jeff/Django/project/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/jeff/Django/project/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/jeff/Django/project/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_markdown/views.py", line 22, in preview
    content=request.REQUEST.get('data', 'No content posted'),
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'REQUEST'
```

Comment: What's with that `REQUEST` attribute, shouldn't be `POST`?

Comment: thats what I thought, but I wasn't 100% positive. This came in a widely used and ditributed pypi package so I assumed it was correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's request object used to have a `REQUEST` attribute that accepted args from GET and POST, but it was deprecated in 1.7 and [removed in 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#features-removed-in-1-9). Your package is not compatible with 1.9.